# Fetching gmail contacts in iphone.?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, google-contacts-api, import-contacts

I am a newbie in IPhone programming.I need to import my gmail contacts to my application.I was successfully done the authentication using gdata api. How i can use this api to import my gmail contacts to my application.Can anybody help me..

Answer (score 2):

Use [GData](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/wiki/GDataObjCIntroduction) for objective-c.

You need to do a read-only checkout from google code, the command is -

`svn checkout gdata-objectivec-client.googlecode.com/svn/trunk gdata-objectivec-client-read-only`

check [this out.](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-objectivec-client/source/checkout) for checkout instructions.

Also this article helped me - how to use [Google API's from iOS](http://johntwang.com/blog/2009/06/08/how-to-use-google-apis-with-iphone-sdk/)

Answer (score 1):

These two tutorials really helped me when I encountered this problem. 
1. http://hoishing.wordpress.com/2011/08/23/gdata-objective-c-client-setup-in-xcode-4/ 
2. http://dipinkrishna.com/blog/2013/07/ios-google-contacts/

Hope it helps! :)