# Fetch Contact from Google in iPhone Application

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-contacts-api

I am working on project in which I have to fetch Contacts from My google Account. I searched but I dont get any Recommanded Library or answer for it.

I found this [Library](https://github.com/google/gdata-objectivec-client) but its for Mac application. I want to fetch contacts in my iPhone application. I found [Google Documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/) but it guided me into other language not in IOS.

Please Any help is appreciated. 

Thank you

Comment: May be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21276606/using-google-plus-api-is-it-possible-to-fetch-gmail-contacts,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9177596/fetching-gmail-contacts-in-iphone,  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37247694/get-google-contacts-using-api-on-ios

Comment: @sailendrak. I will check it. Thanks